# My custom error inside mat-error is not displayed in the DOM

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to validate login form and check if email is valid (I'd like to block some kind of 10minutes mails) so alongside with `mat-errors` for invalid email pattern I wanna display an error that email is not valid or real.

I have an api for that so I'm sending email to the server and it returns me response true of false an I'm trying to display another `mat-error` instead of default one but got stuck in that. I've read about `ErrorStateMatchers` but  I didn't find how to integrate my api service inside. Could you help me or give some hints please.

Here is my html template:

```
<mat-form-field class="form-input">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <span class="material-icons">person</span>
    <input matInput class="input" type="email" name="email" (blur)="validateEmail()" formControlName="email"
      [readonly]="disabledForm">
  </div>

  <mat-error class="input-error" *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').touched && formErrorsText['email']" translate>
    {{ formErrorsText['email'] }}
  </mat-error>

  <mat-error class="input-error" *ngIf="!(validEmail$ | async)">
    {{ 'AUTH.LOGIN.INVALID_EMAIL'| translate }}
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Basically if I replace

```
<mat-error class="input-error" *ngIf="!(validEmail$ | async)">
  {{ 'AUTH.LOGIN.INVALID_EMAIL'| translate }}
</mat-error>
```

with

```
<div class="input-error" *ngIf="!(validEmail$ | async)">
  {{ 'AUTH.LOGIN.INVALID_EMAIL'| translate }}
</div>
```

it's been displayed, but I wanna understand why I can't use `mat-error`.

Here is my `apiService`

```
validateEmail(): void {
 if (this.loginForm.valid) {
   this.validEmail$ = this.emailValidationService.checkEmail(this.loginForm.get('email').value)
    .pipe(map(response => !response?.trust_rate || response?.trust_rate < 50));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `validateEmail()` method, you could do something like

```
validateEmail(): void {
 if (this.loginForm.valid) {
   this.emailValidationService.checkEmail(this.loginForm.get('email').value)
       .subscribe(response => {
         //Apply your checks, if invalid then
         this.loginForm.get('email').setErrors({serverError: 'Your Error'});
       });
```

And in your template,

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('email').errors?.serverError">
   {{ form.get('email').errors?.serverError }}
</mat-error>
```

mat-error seems to be bound to the status of the `<form-field>` it is enclosed in and hence setting an error on the form field correctly marks the field dirty.